# How to express a power of 2 as a recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion

algorithm

```
fun(n)
  if n==1 or n==2 
     return 1
  else 
     return fun(1)+fun(2)+...+fun(n-1)
```

my code

```
def fun(n):
sum = 0
if n == 1 or n == 2:
    return 1
else:
    for i in range(n):
        sum += fun(i)
return sum
```

I am trying to express the following algorithm as a recursive function, but I wonder if my code is a recursive function. If it is not a recursive function, how do we modify the code to make it a recursive function?

Comment: Are you for some reason restricted to using `+` as only operator? It seems so...

Comment: I am learning algorithms in a school class. For the experimental calculation, I would like to compare T(n+1) and T(n) when writing the code as follows and assuming that the time complexity is T(n).

Comment: I want to find the time complexity of each when implementing an algorithm with a recursive function and when using an array. But first, I don't know if the code I wrote is a code that uses a recursive function.

Comment: Please only ask one question. Stick with the "how to implement?" one.

Comment: My question is, for a given algorithm, whether the code I've written is Python code using "recursive functions".

Comment: What definition of "recursice" are you using? Can you apply it to your code which within a function conditionally calls that same function?

Comment: f(2) returns 1, whereas 2 to the 1 is 2. What do you mean by ```power of 2```?

Comment: I see, well if we define a ```recursive``` function as a function that calls itself from within, function OP provided is a recursive function.

Comment: f(n)= 2^(n-3) n>=3 can be expressed as the sum of f(k) where k is 1 to n-1, and this expression is written in Python code by recursion.

Comment: So that does answer your question, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes I got the answer I was looking for. I didn't mean to modify the code or expect an answer. I'm sorry for asking you to feel that way. I'll be careful. thank you for your answer.

Comment: So "f(n)= 2^(n-3) n>=3 can be expressed as the sum of f(k) where k is 1 to n-1" is a quote from the assignment and you are expected to use it? Note that the existing answer does not. Though the answerer (@ShaileshSuryawanshi) cannot be blamed because you did not specify in time....

Comment: I get a feeling that the way you asked got you an answer which does not match your assignment. Consider [edit]ing your question, quoting the full assignment and otherwise using the compromise described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions But on the other hand, that would probably mean creatig a moving target. If it would fundamentally change the question and invalidate the existing answer it would be better to ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help till the end. I think I'm confusing you by asking the wrong way. From now on, I will refer to other questions and ask them in a proper way. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Other Generic approach to recursive algorithm will be something like below. Assumption here is the power is calcualated only of positive numbers.

```
func powerFunc(power, number){
       if power == 0 || number ==1 {
           return 1
       }
       
       return number* powerFunc(power-1,number)
}
```

From the algorithm OP provided in question if we provide `n=2` considering `2^2` is 4. The algorithm returns wrong answer as 1.

Comment: Nice use of a different language for an answer to an algorithm question without a language tag. ;-)

Comment: remove `number == 1` from the condition. `powerFunc(1, 2)` must return 2, not 1.

Comment: It will return 2. Here is implementation in GoLang https://play.golang.org/p/zjmBgmKRivH